# Removing Border from Layer List Symbology

Tags: layers, symbology, borders

When I launched my webapp on our server I noticed these little black boundary boxes appeared around the symbology in my layer list. This is my first webapp deployed using WebAppDev so I'm fairly new with where to look to update things in the code. I've been able to update a few other things (color of text) by inspecting the code in the webapplication on a browser and tracing it back to the source from there but I'm not getting a straightforward answer on this one for some reason. I've messed around in the widgets->LayerList->css->style.css file (.jimu-widget-layerList .col-showLegend and .jimu-widget-layerList .showLegend-div) and tried adding a color and background-color to both of those but those attempts didn't render a succesful output.

[image]